# How does one add a RWX section to a gcc executable for Raspberry Pi

Tags: assembly, linker, linker-scripts

I am trying to add a section (in addition to predefined ones).  I want the section to be RWX.

What I have so far is:

```
SECTIONS
{
  .dictionary :
  {
        *(.dictionary)
  }
}
INSERT AFTER .text;
```

I use the `-T` linker option.

I want to place executable code in it at runtime. Sort of like a writable .text section

I understand how to make the .text section writable via the linker `-N` option but prefer not to take that approach to avoid accidental writes. Also, it precludes the use of shared libraries.

I also understand how to mark the stack as executable via the linker `-zexecstack` option, and am using it currently, but would like to see if appending a new section is possible.

I have difficulty understanding the default linker script obtained by a listing of the --verbose linker option.

When I used the above, I can link just fine.  I can try and place executable code inside the section, but the executable crashes.

Anyone has any pointers, or preferably a working solution?  The basic requirement is to have a new section in which I can allocate space, place executable code in it, and then execute from it.

Comment: As an alternative, what about memmap() at runtime to allocate and then copy the data over?

Comment: Using an executable stack, which is my fallback, is preferable to using memmap().

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I may have stumbled on the answer.  The `-zexecstack` solution works but places the data far outside the branch via BL on a Cortex M0+ processor.

So, I tried following the notes here: https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Section.html

And instead simply declared a section as follows in my .s assembly file:

```
.section ".dictionary", #alloc, #write, #execinstr
.align 2
H_START:
.space 0x20000
H_END:
```

This works like a charm and addresses my issue.